# baposter multi-line headerbox

Tags: baposter

I'm preparing a poster with *baposter* package, and I have a long header in the headerbox so it exceeds the limit. Is there any way to write the header in the headerbox in multi-line?

Comment: For our *and* your benefit, could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: You can always put that header inside a `minipage` or `\parbox` or a simple `tabular`. But without code, it is difficult to advice more.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, this is where the title is defined in `baposter.cls`

```
\ifbaposter@eyecatcher% Has eye catcher%
  \draw (image.east) node(title)[anchor=west,text width=\baposter@titleimage@textwidth]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\baposter@titleimage@textwidth}%
      \begin{center}%
      \textbf{\Huge #3}\\%
      {\Large #4}%
      \end{center}%
    \end{minipage}
  };%
\else% Has no eye catcher
  \draw (image.east) node(title)[anchor=west]  { {\begin{minipage}{\baposter@titleimage@textwidth}{\bfseries\Huge #3}\\{\Large #4}\end{minipage}} };%
\fi
```

Obviously, the fontsize used are `Huge` and `Large`, while the tikz node where they are ''hosted'' has no specific font size defined, which will cause bad line spacing. I'd recommend doing it slightly differently and modifying this portion of code such as

- the font size is correctly set inside the tikz node
- the #3 and #4 contents are in two different nodes
- the minipage environment is avoided

This would mean some code like this (for the if part, to be adapted for the else part):

```
  \draw (image.east) node(title)[anchor=west,text width=\baposter@titleimage@textwidth,text badly centered,font=\Huge\bfseries]{#3};
  \node[below of=title,anchor=west,text width=\baposter@titleimage@textwidth,text badly centered,font=\Large]{#4};
```

Note that the `positioning` library of tikz might be requested if not already defined in the class header.

Answer (score 1):

```
\headerbox{$\begin{array}{l}\vspace{-1.5cm}\\
\text{text in first line}\\ \text{ text in second line}\\ \text{text in third line}
\end{array}$
}{boxheaderheight=2.4cm,name=text,column=0,row=0}{ text}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation/comment to your solution?

Comment: Why use an `array` rather than a `tabular`?

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
\begin{poster}{% other declarations
   headerheight=.125\textheight,% this defines height of box reserved for title, name, etc.
   %another declarations
   }
```