# Separation between title lines in baposter template

Tags: baposter

I am writing a poster with the baposter template. The problem is when the title needs two sentences they are too close to each other.

How can I increase the separation between them?

Thank you very much,
Ignacio

PD: I add an example

```
\documentclass[portrait,final,a0paper,fontscale=0.32]{baposter}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\SET}[1]  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}}
\newcommand{\MAT}[1]  {\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\VEC}[1]  {\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Video}{\SET{V}}
\newcommand{\video}{\VEC{f}}
\newcommand{\track}{x}
\newcommand{\Track}{\SET T}
\newcommand{\LMs}{\SET L}
\newcommand{\lm}{l}
\newcommand{\PosE}{\SET P}
\newcommand{\posE}{\VEC p}
\newcommand{\negE}{\VEC n}
\newcommand{\NegE}{\SET N}
\newcommand{\Occluded}{\SET O}
\newcommand{\occluded}{o}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hspace*{#1}}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}
\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}
\begin{poster}%
 % Poster Options
 {
  grid=false,
  colspacing=1em,
  bgColorOne=white,
  bgColorTwo=white,
  borderColor=lightblue,
  headerColorOne=black,
  headerColorTwo=lightblue,
  headerFontColor=white,
  boxColorOne=white,
  boxColorTwo=lightblue,
  textborder=roundedleft,
  eyecatcher=true,
  headerborder=closed,
  headerheight=0.15\textheight,
  headershape=roundedright,
  headershade=shadelr,
  headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, %Sans Serif
  textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}},
  boxshade=plain,
  background=plain,
  linewidth=2pt
  }
  % Eye Catcher
  {}
   % Title
   {\bf\textsc{Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake }\vspace{0.25em}}
  % Authors
  {Authors\\
   University\\
    mail@mail.com}

  \headerbox{Abstract}{name=problem,column=0,span=3, row=0}{Text}
  \headerbox{Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,  below=problem}{Text}
  \headerbox{References}{name=references,column=0, above=bottom}{Text}
  \headerbox{Conclusions}{name=results,column=1,span=2, above=bottom}{Text} 
  \headerbox{Results}{name=Shaped-Beam,below=problem, above=results,column=1,span=2,row=0}{Text}
  \headerbox{Some Maths}{name=method,column=0,below=introduction,above=references}{Text}
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

This is a complete hack but I had this problem as well and needed to solve it quickly. If someone has a more 'official' solution please share it!

Looking at the `baposter.cls` file I found the `eyecatcher` section where the title is set up. I surrounded the title with custom spacing from the `setspace` package (see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Line_Spacing)). This messed up the eyecatcher a bit since it has a fixed vertical size so I needed to remove some of the vertical space introduced using the `vspace` command. My additions are shown below, but you may want to play with the numbers passed to `spacing` and `vspace`. Note that the `#3` and `#4` indicate the Title and Authors text passed in from your `.tex` file.

```
% set in preamble
\usepackage{setspace} % added
...
\ifbaposter@eyecatcher% Has eye catcher%                                    
   \draw (image.east) node(title)[anchor=west,text, width=\baposter@titleimage@textwidth]{%
     \begin{minipage}{\baposter@titleimage@textwidth}                       
       \begin{center}                                                       
         \begin{spacing}{2.0} % added                                              
           \textbf{\Huge #3}\\                                              
         \end{spacing}        % added                                               
         \vspace{-1em}        % added                                               
       {\Large #4}%                                                          
       \end{center}%                                                         
     \end{minipage}                                                          
   };
...
```

Again, a non-hacked solution would be more ideal but I can't see an easy way to do it in this case.

Comment: For an alternative solution (but one that also involves rewriting the `baposter` code) see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220217/2693. This answer correctly identifies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky solution that needs less code is to create a manual line break and incorporate a vertical space

```
% Title
{\bf\textsc{Title Fake Title Fake \\ \vspace{0.2em} Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake }\vspace{0.25em}}
```

The width of 0.2em seems to work fine for my case. If it pushes the first line of the page you might have to put a negative vertical space before the first line:

```
% Title
    {\bf\textsc{\vspace{-0.4em}Title Fake Title Fake \\ \vspace{0.4em} Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake Title Fake }\vspace{0.25em}}
```