# Multiple lines in header box, baposter

Tags: baposter

This [article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168991/baposter-multi-line-headerbox/199630) doesn't really help me further. I have a headerbox:

```
\begin{posterbox}[column=0,below=auto]{Conversion of Mechanical Energy to Heat}

Latin random Text 

\end{posterbox}
```

I have two columns, so the title of this box doesn't fill in. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please make it a minimal working example? And also please describe the problem clearer or just include a screenshot.

Comment: Use the boxheaderheight key to adjust the height of the posterbox title, like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443516